# Scipy normalization-- localize values to set discrete points

Tags: python, pyqt, scipy

I am currently displaying two separate 2D images (x,y plane and z,y plane) that are derived from 96x512 arrays of 0-255 values.  I would like to be able to filter the data so that anything under a certain value is done away with (the highest values are indicative of targets).  What I would like to be able to do is from these images, separate discrete points that may be then mapped three-dimensionally as points, rather than mapping two intersecting planes.  I'm not entirely sure how to do this or where to start (I'm very new to python).  I am producing the images using scipy and have done some normalization and noise reduction, but I'm not sure how to then separate out anything over the threshold as it's own individual point.  Is this possible?

Comment: If possible, could you give an example (small) dataset and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Yikes, I'm not sure how I would do that.  The values for the arrays are parsed out of massive binary files.  I would ideally want the output to be a list of x,y and z,y coordinates (one list from each image) that I could then plot.  Does that help? (sorry if not)

Comment: What code are you using to produce the images? matplotlib, or something else? What type of images (I can think of dozens)? One straightforward solution is to set the colormap such that anything below a certain value is white, and then greyscale up to black. But you'll have to show some (plotting) code before we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, filtering points can be done like this:

```
A=numpy.random.rand(5,5)
B=A>0.5
```

Now B is a binary mask, and you can use it in a number of ways:

```
A[B]
```

will return an array with all values of A that are true in B.

```
A[B]=0
```

will assign 0 to all values in A that are true in B.

```
numpy.nonzero(B)
```

will give you the x,y coordinates of each point that is true in B.